# Python, review and speed up A* algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, path-finding

I have implemented an A* algorithm to find the shortest path between two points in a grid world. For large path lengths the algorithm takes a very long time. I was first wondering if my implementation is correct, and if any optimization could take place?

The arguments for the `aStar` algorithm, are the current position of you and the position you desire to travel to as `(x,y)`  tuples.

The `Node.value` of a node is a direction to travel (NSEW), `getAdjacentNodes()` returns a list of nodes directly adjacent to this one that we can travel to.

```
#Perform an A* search to find the best path to the dirt
  def aStar(self, current, end):
    openSet = set()   #Set of explorable nodes
    openHeap = []     #All paths heap, lowest cost on top
    closedSet = set() #Best path so far
    curNode = Node(0, current, self.manHatDist(current, end))
    openSet.add(curNode)
    openHeap.append((curNode.cost,curNode))
    while openSet:
      curNode = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]
      if curNode.pos == end:
          return self.getDirections(curNode)
      openSet.remove(curNode)
      closedSet.add(curNode)
      for tile in self.getAdjacentNodes(curNode.pos):
         if tile not in closedSet:
             tile.parent = curNode
             tile.cost = self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end) + self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, current) + curNode.cost
             if tile not in openSet:
                 openSet.add(tile)
                 heapq.heappush(openHeap, (tile.cost,tile))
    return []

  #Get the moves made to get to this endNode
  def getDirections(self, endNode):
    moves = []
    tmpNode = endNode
    while tmpNode.parent is not None:
      moves.append(tmpNode.value)
      tmpNode = tmpNode.parent
    moves.reverse()
    return moves
```

Node class

```
# Node class for A* search
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, pos, cost):
    self.pos = pos
    self.cost = cost
    self.value = value
    self.parent = None

  def __lt__(a, b):
    if(a.cost < b.cost):
      return 1
    return 0

  def __gt__(a, b):
    if(a.cost > b.cost):
      return 1
    return 0
```

EDIT - Here is the `getAdjacentNodes` method

```
  #Return all possible moves from given tile as Node objects
  def getAdjacentNodes(self, curPos):
    allMoves = ['North','South','East','West']
    posMoves = []
    for direction in allMoves:
      if(self.canMove(direction, curPos)):
        posMoves.append(Node(direction, self.getLocIfMove(curPos, direction), 0))
    return posMoves
```

EDIT2 - Profiling result

[Profile Result Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uBsUKMu9)

Comment: The code doesn't look too bad to me, I did a similar one looking for a path in a maze image about the same way.  You can gain a little in your for tile in ... loop by assigning a local variable in the loop to tile so python doesn't have to look it up every time you use it.  ie t = tile and use t throughout the rest of the loop, not tile.  Have you tried profiling and seeing where it is hanging up most?  http://cyrille.rossant.net/profiling-and-optimizing-python-code/

Comment: Something like `for t=tile in adjacentNodes` ?

Comment: for tile in tiles: t = tile and use t thoughout, not tile

Comment: a better profiling link too, http://pymotw.com/2/profile/

Comment: +1 to a line profiler. // I have several questions. Why did you choose A* (A* is hardly the best algorithm out there)? Is Numpy an option? Why do your `__lt__`/`__gt__` classes return `1`/`0` and not `return a.cost > b.cost`? Is this Python 3? Does avoiding classes give you any speed boost (remember that `tuple`s have a sorting order)?

Comment: We're learning A* in my class, I wanted to get it working first before I tried to implement a different/more advanced A* type algorithm. -- Didn't return lt/gt cause I'm not as smart as I'd hope (thanks) -- What do you mean by avoid classes? --== I'm new to python, this is my first program written in it.

Comment: @Veedrac could you link me to some algorithms that are better than A*? I can't find a good example.

Comment: For this problem (shortest path in uniform-cost square grid), consider [jump point search](http://harablog.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/jump-point-search/).

Comment: +1 for JPS. // @BumSkeeter; Using `tuple`s would have a lower initialisation cost than classes (also see `namedtuple`s and classes' `__slots__` attribute). If initialising and `__lt__`/`__gt__` calls are significant (**profile**) it might be better to use them. // Also this is quite clean for a first shot at Python. +1 to thee.

Comment: So instead of my `Node` class I might think about using tuples? // Thanks! I keep getting errors for no `:`! lol

Comment: @BumSkeeter Yes, but **profile**. I'm *guessing* at what *might* be slow. If you use [a line profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) and give us the output we'll be able to give a lot more targeted advice.

Comment: Ok, give me one second I have one running now, ill put it up as a link in an edit.

Comment: You should use `def __init__(self, value, pos, cost=None):` if you want to have non-initialised attributes. `None` will correctly throw errors *loudly* and you avoid initialising by just not passing that attribute at initialisation.

Comment: I've added the profiling result as an edit

Comment: I recommend sorting by `tottime` and not `cumtime` because the former looks at the time not delegated to other functions. Further I recommend  a line profiler as well. // wrt. the results, what's up with that `copy.deepcopy` call? Where are you performing it and how can you remove it? It's taking way over half of the time here.

Comment: If you are looking for advice on how to improve your code, http://codereview.stackexchange.com  might provide better answers.


Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong to me:

```
for tile in self.getAdjacentNodes(curNode.pos):
    if tile not in closedSet:
        tile.parent = curNode
        tile.cost = self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end) + self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, current) + curNode.cost
        if tile not in openSet:
            openSet.add(tile)
            heapq.heappush(openHeap, (tile.cost,tile))
```

First problem. The computation of the cost of the new tile is:

```
self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end) + self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, current) + curNode.cost
```

but it ought to be:

```
curNode.cost
- self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end)
+ self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, tile.pos)
+ self.manHatDist(tile.pos, end)
```

(You could avoid the subtraction in the computation of the cost of the new tile if you were cleverer about the way you represent the search nodes, but I will leave that to you.)

Second problem. Having discovered that `tile` is not in `closedSet`, you immediately assume that the best way to get to `tile` is via `curNode`. But isn't it possible that `tile` is already in `openSet`? If so, there might be another route to `tile` that's better than the one via `curNode`.* So this code ought to read:

```
for tile in self.getAdjacentNodes(curNode.pos):
    if tile not in closedSet:
        cost = (curNode.cost
                - self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end)
                + self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, tile.pos)
                + self.manHatDist(tile.pos, end))
        if tile not in openSet or cost < tile.cost:
            tile.parent = curNode
            tile.cost = cost
            openSet.add(tile)
            heapq.heappush(openHeap, (cost,tile))
```

I can't say if this will solve your performance problems. But it might give better results.

* There couldn't be a shorter route if `self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, tile.pos)` is always 1. But if that's the case, why bother with the `euclidDist` method?

Comment: (I don't know much about A*) What's the justification for your first point? aka. What's the subtraction needed for?

Comment: @Veedrac: you probably want to read up on [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). If you understand the admissibility heuristic but still don't understand my first point, then do come back and ask.

Comment: @GarethRees if you look at my edit I added the `getAdjacentNodes` method source. In it, I never set the cost of a node to anything. Doesn't think make the line `or cost < tile.cost:` erroneous?

Comment: @GarethRees Thanks for that. The variable names were throwing me off (heh, that sounds like an excuse).

Comment: @BumSkeeter: The `or` operator in Python is short-circuiting, so `cost < tile.cost` will only be evaluated if `tile not in openSet` is false, and in that case `tile.cost` was set when `tile` was added to `openSet`.

Comment: I've taken @Veedrac's advice and set `cost=None` for my new nodes. Seeing as no errors are thrown, does this prove your point @Gareth Rees? But still, how can it be so still, `tile` comes from the list `getAdjacentNode` produces, so tile will never have a cost because `tile` never has its cost set unless it is put in the `openSet`, and still `tile` is never set to anything from `openSet`. // if that made sense..?

Comment: Ah, I see your point now. But this is much worse than I was expecting -- if `getAdjacentNodes` always produces fresh tiles, then how can you possibly expect these tiles to be found in `closedSet` or `openSet`?

Comment: Hmm, so I probably need to send `closeSet` and `openSet` to the `getAdjacentNodes`, and if one of the adjacent nodes I produce is in one of the sets, then copy it to the list of adjacent nodes returned?

Comment: That would be one approach. Basically you must ensure that you always generate the same `Node` for the same position, so that you can avoid revisiting that position in the course of your search (and so end up going round in circles). I think we have found the cause of your program's poor performance.

Comment: I seem to be having an issue with this, here is a whole nother question if your up to it. :)! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128695/python-a-implmentation-issues-keeping-track-of-tiles