# Keeping track of tiles in a* search

Tags: python, search, a-star

I am having a hard time keeping track of the tiles generated by `getAdjacentTiles(..)`. I have identified the performance issue of my A* implementation below is that I do not keep track of the tiles that have seen before, every call to `getAdjacentTiles` returns new tiles (`Node`'s) and not any of the tiles in `openSet` or `closedSet`. I decided to use a list of Node objects as all of the tiles created so far, and pass that to `getAdjacentTiles` to determine if a tile it produces has already been visited.

My problem is, that I cannot seem to keep track of these tiles properly. Whenever my A* needs to take more than about 4 movements to get to the `end` location it craps out. Which I am sure has to do with how I am trying to keep track of the tiles (again `Node`'s that have been visited) I would have to suspect the issue is with my knowledge of python, am I allowed to do `.apped(tile)` like I do in `getAdjacentTiles(...)` when looping through the `allTiles` set?

[Here's a link to the question that led me to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125808/python-review-and-speed-up-a-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment28286863_19125808)

The error generated (sometimes, only when the A* path is longer than about 3 steps..)

```
File "P3.py", line 67, in aStar
 openSet.remove(curNode) 
KeyError: <__main__.Node instance at 0xa39edcc>
```

Source

```
  #Perform an A* search to find the best path to the dirt
  def aStar(self, current, end):
    openSet = set()
    openHeap = []
    closedSet = set()
    allTiles = set()
    curNode = Node(0, current, self.manHatDist(current, end))
    openSet.add(curNode)
    allTiles.add(curNode)
    openHeap.append((curNode.cost,curNode))
    while openSet:
      curNode = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]
      if curNode.pos == end:
          return self.getDirections(curNode)
      openSet.remove(curNode)
      closedSet.add(curNode)
      adjNodes = self.getAdjacentNodes(curNode.pos, allTiles)
      for tile in adjNodes:
        t = tile
        if t not in closedSet:
          cost = (curNode.cost - self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end) 
                  + self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, current)
                  + self.manHatDist(t.pos, end))
          if t not in openSet or cost < t.cost:
            t.parent = curNode
            t.cost = cost
            openSet.add(t)
            heapq.heappush(openHeap, (cost,t))
        allTiles.add(t)
    return []

  #Get the moves made to get to this endNode
  def getDirections(self, endNode):
    moves = []
    tmpNode = endNode
    while tmpNode.parent is not None:
      moves.append(tmpNode.value)
      tmpNode = tmpNode.parent
    moves.reverse()
    return moves

  #Return all possible moves from given tile as Node objects
  def getAdjacentNodes(self, curPos, allTiles):
    allMoves = ['North','South','East','West']
    posMoves = []
    for direction in allMoves:
      if(self.canMove(direction, curPos)):
        posMoves.append(Node(direction, self.getLocIfMove(curPos, direction)))
    retNodes = []
    for posLocNode in posMoves:
      set = False
      for tile in allTiles:
        if(posLocNode.pos == tile.pos):
          set = True
          retNodes.append(tile)
      if(not set):
        retNodes.append(posLocNode)
    return retNodes
```

Comment: Can you print `openSet` on each step?

Comment: Why is there a capital H in `manHatDist`?

Comment: Its Man Hatten Island... Its German for "man has that island", traces back to when George Washington bought Louisiana territory and as a present to the German's let them name the Island (the most prominent land mass of the Louisiana purchase) ///jk//// I'm not sure why I capitalized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fire up the interactive interpreter and see what we can find. (You didn't give the name of your class in the question, so I've called it `Search`.)

```
>>> Search().aStar((0,0), (2,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "q19128695.py", line 25, in aStar
    openSet.remove(curNode)
KeyError: <__main__.Node instance at 0x104895518>
```

OK, the first problem is that these `Node` instances are not self-explanatory. We can't do anything with "Node instance at 0x104895518", so let's add a `__repr__` method to the `Node` class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Node({0.value}, {0.pos}, {0.cost})'.format(self)
```

and try again:

```
>>> Search().aStar((0,0), (2,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "q19128695.py", line 25, in aStar
    openSet.remove(curNode)
KeyError: Node(East, (1, 2), 3.41421356237)
```

OK, that's more informative. Let's fire up the [Python debugger](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and do a [postmortem](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.pm):

```
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.pm()
> q19128695.py(25)aStar()
-> openSet.remove(curNode)
(Pdb) openSet
set([Node(North, (2, -1), 6.0), Node(East, (2, 2), 4.65028153987), 
     Node(West, (-1, 1), 5.0), Node(North, (0, -1), 5.0),
     Node(South, (1, 3), 6.65028153987), Node(South, (0, 3), 6.0), 
     Node(East, (3, 0), 6.0), Node(West, (-1, 0), 5.0),
     Node(North, (1, -1), 5.0), Node(East, (3, 1), 6.65028153987),
     Node(West, (-1, 2), 6.0)])
(Pdb) closedSet
set([Node(0, (0, 0), 4), Node(South, (2, 1), 3.41421356237),
     Node(East, (1, 1), 3.0), Node(South, (0, 1), 3.0),
     Node(East, (2, 0), 3.0), Node(East, (1, 0), 3.0),
     Node(East, (1, 2), 3.41421356237), Node(South, (0, 2), 3.0)])
(Pdb) curNode
Node(East, (1, 2), 3.41421356237)
(Pdb) curNode in closedSet
True
```

So the node has already been closed. How could this have happened? Well, it could happen if the node had been added to `openSet` and `openHeap` twice. It would then be popped from `openHeap` twice (because heaps can have multiple identical items), but it can only be removed from `openSet` once. The code in question looks like this:

```
if t not in openSet or cost < t.cost:
    t.parent = curNode
    t.cost = cost
    openSet.add(t)
    heapq.heappush(openHeap, (cost,t))
```

The first problem with this, is that you push the pair `(cost, t)` even though you've gone to the trouble to give your `Node` objects `__lt__` and `__gt__` methods. Instead, just push `t` onto the heap:

```
heapq.heappush(openHeap, t)
```

This requires a couple of changes elsewhere: instead of

```
openHeap.append((curNode.cost,curNode))
while openSet:
    curNode = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]
```

you'll have to write

```
openHeap = [curNode]
while openSet:
    curNode = heapq.heappop(openHeap)
```

Now, the second problem (which is my fault—sorry), is that if `t` is already in `openSet` then we shouldn't add it to the heap again. Instead, we should re-heapify:

```
t_open = t in openSet
if not t_open or cost < t.cost:
    t.parent = curNode
    t.cost = cost
    if t_open:
        heapq.heapify(openHeap)
    else:
        openSet.add(t)
        heapq.heappush(openHeap, t)
```

Going back to the debugger output, recall this:

```
(Pdb) curNode
Node(East, (1, 2), 3.41421356237)
```

That `3.41421356237` should be worrying you: shouldn't the cost always be an integer? It looks as though the cost calculation is still wrong. It says:

```
    cost = (curNode.cost
            - self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end) 
            + self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, current)
            + self.manHatDist(t.pos, end))
```

but that third line should say:

```
            + self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, t.pos)
```

So, with all those fixes in place, let's try again:

```
>>> Search().aStar((0,0), (2,2))
['North', 'North', 'East', 'East']
```

#### Replies to comments

1. "How did you call `Search().aStar(...)` from the interpreter?" I ran the interpreter and then typed in that line of code at the interpreter prompt. [See the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html).
2. "So the Euclidean distance will always be one." Yes, if you're searching for paths in a uniform-cost grid, then the Euclidean distance between neighbours will always be the same.
3. "Now that I think about it, `curNode.cost - self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end)` is always equal to zero." That's not right. In your implementation, the `cost` of a search node is (i) the cost of reaching that node from the start, *plus* (ii) an admissible estimate of the cost of reaching the end from that node. So if you subtract the admissible estimate then you should get back to (i) again.

Comment: Thank you, how did you call `Search().aStar(..)` from the interpreter? // You just taught me debugging in python, thank you. // I see now what you meant in the linked post in my question above, `self.euclidDist(curNode.pos, t.pos)` will always be equal to one, t is always and only a node either NSEW of the `curNode`; so the euclidean distance will always be one. // Well I guess now that I think about it `curNode.cost - self.manHatDist(curNode.pos, end)` is always equal to zero. I think I got tripped up with heuristics and admissibility. //